# Struts2 : How to determine action dynamically with Struts2 Tag Submit button

Tags: struts2

```
<head>
<title>Struts 2 Login Application!</title>
</head>
<body>
<s:form action="login" method="POST" validate="true">
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
Login
</td>
</tr>
<s:actionerror />
<s:fielderror />
<s:textfield name="username" label="Login name"/>
<s:password name="password" label="Password"/>
<s:submit value="Login" align="center"/>
<s:submit value="Logout" align="center"/>
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hi ,

I have this Form made up of Struts2 Tags .

My question is , how can i determine the action dynamically ? Means when the user clicks on Login Submit button , it should call the action login and if the user clicks on Logout Submit button , it should call the action logout ?

Please tell me how to do this ??

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use URL tag to handle such use-case which will provide you more flexibility and easy to use, all you have to do something like

```
<s:url id="login" action="login" method="login"> </s:url>
<s:url id="logout" action="logout" method="logout"> </s:url>
```

Alternate way to use action property of submit tag all you have to provide action in your submit button

```
<s:submit value="Logout" align="center" action="logout"/>
```

S2 also provides another way to handle multiple submit buttons in your page, please refer to the document for details

- [multiple-submit-buttons](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/multiple-submit-buttons.html)